# Scoreboard for Game, Having problems with using Array in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, leaderboard

Hi I am integrating an internal offline localized leaderboard for a game I have created.

Getting a bit lost using Array & Shared Object.

I thought this would work but when I trace values they return as [object Object]

the code wrote is:

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;

var HScores:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("HighScoresValues");

// ASSIGN Text Fields to Vars
var USR_Level_Reached = LevelTXT.text;
var USR_Name = PlayerTXT.text;

// array
var highScores:Array = new Array();

if(HScores.data.d_SCORES==undefined)
    {
        HScores.data.d_SCORES = highScores;
    } else {highScores.push({score:int(0) , player:"No Name"}); }

if(HScores.data.d_SCORES)
    {
        highScores = HScores.data.d_SCORES;
    }   

Button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Button1_MouseClickEvent);
function Button1_MouseClickEvent(event:MouseEvent) 
    {
        USR_Level_Reached = LevelTXT.text;
        USR_Name = PlayerTXT.text;

        highScores.push({score:int(USR_Level_Reached) , player:String(USR_Name)});
        highScores.sortOn("score", Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC);

        HScores.data.d_SCORES = highScores;
        HScores.flush();

        trace("Shared Data = "+HScores.data.d_SCORES);
        trace("Array Data = "+highScores);

    }
```

Not sure were am I going wrong, 
but its not passing new text fields to my Array on button press,

though the array seems to be adding blank values to its self 
& also passing its blank values to SharedObjects correctly 
but traces as [object Object], [object Object], [object Object] ?

any ideas?

Comment: You can store these data in a single **Array** of **{"level":12, "name":"Sean Carroll"}** generic objects.

Comment: Thank you, I researched as3 arrays & have become stumped again.   I have updated the question to reflect my latest problems getting Array working.  Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Generic objects will indeed trace like [object Object] because reasons. In order to trace generic objects in readable form you need to **trace(JSON.stringify(...target...))**

Comment: Cool that explains it.   One more question is there a way to make sure data in shared object doesn't get to big ie.  keep only top 15 records in shared object?

Comment: Just check **if (your_array.length > 15) { your_array.length = 15 };** and that's it.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank You!